# Fama French Three Factor

Tags: fama-french

How to calculate the value weighted or equally weighted returns for the six portfolios SL,SM,SH,BL,BM,BH of fama french 3 factor model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are available on their websites.

If you want to build them by yourself, the procedure is well described on their original paper.

In short:

- divide the sample in deciles for each variable
- build long-short portfolios based on these deciles
- aggregate and compare perfomances

Overall, I think you should further detail your question.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, let me detail my question,i already sort data according to size and book to market ratio i want to know that how to calculate the value weighted or equally weighted returns of 6 portfolios in excel for Pakistan Stock Exchange  data.?